# sqlite, slow joined query throught 4 tables

Tags: sqlite

I have query through 4 tables: times, tags, users and categories.
Each table has no more than 400 records, but this query takes 70ms.

I need it many times (400x), so all procedure takes a total of about 30 seconds.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM times
INNER JOIN tags ON times.user_id = tags.tag_id
INNER JOIN users ON tags.user_nr = users.nr
INNER JOIN categories ON users.category_id = categories.id
WHERE (times.time_raw < "000560")
AND (times.time_raw != 0 )
AND (times.cell != 1 )
AND (categories.name="kategory_A")
AND (times.run_id="08")
```

How can I make it faster?

Comment: Instead of using where try using Having clause

Comment: Do you have indexes on those columns? Can you show an execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes is the solution!!

**[The following list gives guidelines in choosing columns to index](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.sql.doc/doc/choosing.columns.to.index.html):**

> •You should create indexes on columns that are used frequently in
>   WHERE clauses.
>   •You should create indexes on columns that are used
>   frequently to join tables.
>   •You should create indexes on columns
>   that are used frequently in ORDER BY clauses.
>   •You should create
>   indexes on columns that have few of the same values or unique values
>   in the table.
>   •You should not create indexes on small tables (tables
>   that use only a few blocks) because a full table scan may be faster
>   than an indexed query.
>   •If possible, choose a primary key that
>   orders the rows in the most appropriate order.
>   •If only one column
>   of the concatenated index is used frequently in WHERE clauses, place
>   that column first in the CREATE INDEX statement.
>   •If more than one
>   column in a concatenated index is used frequently in WHERE clauses,
>   place the most selective column first in the CREATE INDEX statement.